# TypeError: g.getResponseHeader is undefined

Tags: java, http-headers, cors, alfresco, alfresco-share

I have this code:

```
Connector conn = FrameworkUtil.getConnector(context, ALFRESCO_ENDPOINT_ID);
ConnectorContext c = new ConnectorContext(HttpMethod.POST);
c.setContentType("application/json");

Response res = conn.call("/slingshot/profile/userprofile", c,
                    new ByteArrayInputStream(buf.toString().getBytes()));
```

That makes a POST to the link: `POST http://localhost:8080/share/service/components/profile/userprofile`

But, I got the error:

> TypeError: g.getResponseHeader is undefined
>
> ...unction(g){var b=g.argument.config;var
>   f=g.getResponseHeader["Content-Type"]||g....

In a search on the Internet, I saw that this can be a problem that is solved adding Content-Type with CORS.

Something like:

```
 .header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers", "x-requested-with,Content-Type");
```

How can I do this in my code? With Connector or ConnectorContext I don't find a way to set the header...

Or if this is not the way to solve this, how can I solve this error?

Comment: CORS is related to cross origin scripting - meaning you are going across different domains in your client side scripts. Is this true? If not, can you confirm the content-type that is in there is correct? There are many different types... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Content_negotiation

Comment: First, thanks for the answer. I'm in a url: http:localhost:8080/share/page/user/my-name/profile, and i'm trying to access the link that is in the question. And the content is a json. @JohnLee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you might have a few things configured incorrectly here, or you might be misunderstanding a few things. If you're making a remote connection to the ALFRESCO_ENDPOINT_ID then this typically means that you're trying to connect to the Alfresco Repository - and based on where you say you're trying to make the call from it would appear that this is in a Java-backed WebScript running within the Share application - is this correct?

If so, the URL that should be requested would actually be:

```
http://localhost:8080/alfresco/service/slingshot/profile/userprofile
```

Which would be equivalent to calling the following:

```
http://localhost:8080/share/proxy/alfresco/slingshot/profile/userprofile
```

(the second URL automatically proxies to the Alfresco enpoint).

If you have both the Alfresco Repository and Share running in the same server (which the use of the port 8080 implies you do) then you shouldn't be hitting CORS issues - unless you're trying to go from localhost to some remote location where the Alfresco Repository is running.

Share/Surf should be taking care of all of this for you - perhaps you can provide a bit more context on exactly what it is you're trying to do,
where the code is running (e.g. WebScript, Share, etc) and where you're trying to connect to?

This might help in best advising how to solve your main problem.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!! Respository and share are in the same server. If not CORS error, which can be?